# Lock Tab change - TabHost

Tags: android, testing, onclick, tabcontrol, android-tabhost

I used the following method to check if the tab is clicked:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                int i = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

                if (i == 2) {
                    Log.i("Tab Number", "=" + i);
                    testFields(); // Verifies that the data fields were filled.
                }
            }
        });
```

When I check if fields are correct, I have a test "if or else".

If everything is completed, OK !

If not, can not follow to next tab. Have to keep tab "data" to finish filling.

**How to block a change in tab? Until everything is correct?**

**Edited to show the test helps**

```
final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getParent().findViewById(
                android.R.id.tabhost);
        // ONCLICK TABHOST
        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();

                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        String currentTabTag = (String) tabHost
                                .getCurrentTabTag();
                        String clickedTabTag = (String) v.getTag();

                        if ((etCargac.getText().toString().equals(""))
                                || (tsoloSelecionadac.equals("Selecione"))) {
                            return false; // allows tab change
                        }
                        return true; // doesnt allow tab change
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

This event I am trying to do is in another class. It is not within the class of tabhost.
So I have to use the getParent(), correct?

The test I need to do is check the fields "tab1 data" if they are filled.

If nothing is complete should not switch to the "tab3 results"

Answer (score 5):

Using OnTouchListener on each tab, you can easily prevent changing the tab.

```
    for (int i=0; i<tabWidget.getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    String currentTabTag = (String) tabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
                    String clickedTabTag = (String) view.getTag();

                    testFields();

                    if (!fieldAreCorrect) {
                        return true; // does not allow tab change
                    }
                }
                return false; // allows tab change
            }               
        });
    }
```

Comment: worked...But current as well as next tab remain selected...:(